# How to display value labels above graph bars?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to display values above the bars in this graph? I have the values being retrieved from a TSV, but am currently having difficulty getting the bar values to be displayed as labels above each respective bar.

This is the data that I have as TSV:
[image]

This is what I currently have for rendering the graph:

```
margin =
top: 30
right: 30
bottom: 40
left: 60
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom

formatPercent = d3.format("")

x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([width, 0], .1)

y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent)

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent)

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

d3.tsv("/Home/GetTsv/data.tsv", (error, data)->

    data.forEach((d)->
        d.Total = +d.Total
    )

    x.domain(data.map((d)-> d.Year))
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, (d)-> d.Total)])

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", 30)
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Year")

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -60)
        .attr("x", -(height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Total Activity")

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", (d)-> x(d.Year))
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", (d)-> y(d.Total))
        .attr("height", (d)-> height - y(d.Total))

#   svg.selectAll("text")
#       .data(data)
#       .enter()
#       .append("text")
#       .text((d)-> d.Total)
#       .attr("x", (d, i)-> i * (width / data.length))
#       .attr("y", (d)-> height - d)

)
```

This is what my graph looks like:

[image]

But I would like to have labels above the bars, similar to this:

[image]

The code that is commented-out is my attempt at trying to make the value labels show above the bars.

Comment: Is ".attr("y", (d)-> height - d)" returning a value or do you need to change the second d to y(d.total)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasting this code in the text section should do the trick:

```
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * (width / dataset.length) + (width / dataset.length) / 2; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return height - (d * 10) - 10; })
```

the -10 there makes some distance from the bar, in this case 10px obviously. also the other numbers are to be tweaked a bit, i just pasted the code from a file i had so i don't know exactly what it would look like on your code since i don't have the dataset to try.
If it doesn't can you paste the script in http://jsfiddle.net/ so I can try and work it out? Let me know how it works out!